# Is BottomSheetDialogFragment back stack possible?

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottom-sheet

I have a `BottomSheetDialogFragment` that creates another child `Fragment` as its main view.

That child navigates to another `Fragment` as follows: `fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)?.addToBackStack("tag")?.commit()`

but when I press the back button the whole dialog is dismissed.

So is it possible to have a back stack in a `BottomSheetDialogFragment`?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with `childFragmentManager`. Make transaction in child fragment manager of BottomSheetDialogFragment.